# Property "Background" does not support values of type "Frame" error in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I am newbie at xamarin developing. I got an error which says that Property "Background" does not support values of type "Frame". Does anybody know that how to correct syntax? Looks like I have some syntax problems.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="HealNow.MainPage"
             xmlns:ff="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
             xmlns:ffSvg="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
             xmlns:ffTransformations="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Transformations;assembly=FFImageLoading.Transformations">

    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout.Background>
            <Frame>  
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                   <GradientStop Color="#48b6a6" Offset="0.1" ></GradientStop>/>
                   <GradientStop Color="#2b78d4" Offset="1.0" ></GradientStop>/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout.Background>
 </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: if you read the docs, you'll see that `Background` is of type `Brush`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the [documentation of VisualElement.Background Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.background?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_VisualElement_Background) shows, the `Background` property is of type `Brush`. Applying a `Frame` will not work. So the solution is to apply the brush without the frame:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Color="#48b6a6" Offset="0.1" ></GradientStop>/>
             <GradientStop Color="#2b78d4" Offset="1.0" ></GradientStop>/>
         </LinearGradientBrush>
    </StackLayout.Background>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LinearGradientBrush` class derives from the `GradientBrush` class,the `GradientBrush` class derives from the `Brush` class,and instances of these brush types can be assigned to the `Stroke` and `Fill` properties of a `Shape`, and the `Background` property of a `VisualElement`.

So you should use `Frame.Background` or `StackLayout.Background`.

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
               <GradientStop Color="#48b6a6" Offset="0.1" ></GradientStop>/>
               <GradientStop Color="#2b78d4" Offset="1.0" ></GradientStop>/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
    </StackLayout.Background>
</StackLayout>
```

or

```
<StackLayout>
       <Frame ...>
         <Frame.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
               <GradientStop Color="#48b6a6" Offset="0.1" ></GradientStop>/>
               <GradientStop Color="#2b78d4" Offset="1.0" ></GradientStop>/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
         </Frame.Background>
       </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```